# Why gwt event bubbling doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, gwt, event-handling

I have a custom widget with a constructor body like this

```
  public MyWidget() {

            this.containerDiv = DOM.createDiv();
            this.containerDiv.getStyle().setPosition(Position.ABSOLUTE);
    this.containerDiv.getStyle().setLeft(20, Style.Unit.PX);
    this.containerDiv.getStyle().setTop(20, Style.Unit.PX);
    this.containerDiv.getStyle().setWidth(50, Style.Unit.PX);
    this.containerDiv.getStyle().setHeight(20, Style.Unit.PX);

    final Element canvasContainer = DOM.createDiv();
    canvasContainer.getStyle().setPosition(Position.ABSOLUTE);
    canvasContainer.getStyle().setLeft(0, Style.Unit.PX);
    canvasContainer.getStyle().setTop(0, Style.Unit.PX);
    canvasContainer.getStyle().setBottom(0, Style.Unit.PX);
    canvasContainer.getStyle().setRight(20, Style.Unit.PX);

            this.canvas = DOM.createCanvas();
    this.canvas.getStyle().setWidth(100, Unit.PCT);
    this.canvas.getStyle().setHeight(100, Unit.PCT);

    canvasContainer.appendChild(this.canvas);
    this.containerDiv.appendChild(canvasContainer);

    setElement(this.containerDiv);

    DOM.sinkEvents((Element) this.canvas.cast(), Event.ONCLICK);
    DOM.setEventListener((Element) this.canvas.cast(), new EventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBrowserEvent(final Event event) {

            Window.alert("canvas  click");
        }
    });

    DOM.sinkEvents((Element) canvasContainer.cast(), Event.ONCLICK);
    DOM.setEventListener(canvasContainer, new EventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBrowserEvent(final Event event) {

            Window.alert("Bubble click");
        }
    });
    DOM.sinkEvents((Element) this.containerDiv.cast(), Event.ONCLICK);
    DOM.setEventListener(this.containerDiv, new EventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBrowserEvent(final Event event) {

            Window.alert("Container click");
        }
    });

   }
```

and it produces html like this

```
<div style="position: absolute; left: 20px; top: 20px; width: 50px; height: 20px; ">
  <div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; right: 20px; ">
    <canvas style="width: 100%; height: 100%; "/>
  </div>
</div>
```

when I click the canvas I get two alerts "canvas  click" and "Bubble click" but no "Container click".

Why ?

Comment: Here's the supposedly equivalent pure javascript code in jsbin for debugging: http://jsbin.com/alefeq/edit - when I click on the canvas it works here.

Comment: What's the type of containerDiv?

Comment: By the way, why don't you use GWT's own Element/Widget classes' addOnClickHandler, etc...? You'll probably avoid the kind of problems described by pistolPanties' answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add your widget its `onAttach()` method is called. If you check the source of this method you will notice it redefines the event listener for browser events to be the widget by `DOM.setEventListener(getElement(), this)`. And according to javadocs of this function only one such listener may exist for a single element.  Since your containerDiv is returned by `getElement()` of widget, the onBrowserEvent you have defined for your element is replaced by the default onBrowserEvent implementation of the widget. That is why the `Window.alert()` is never called