# Handle click events for multiple links in gwt

Tags: gwt

How to handle click events on multiple links in a GWT. Currently I am using gwt-bootstrap component "Navlink" element for links. There are around 50+ links in a page. I am using uibinder for view part. Links are added in uibinder xml. how to handle which link is selected.
I don't want to give uifield for each link and then handle click event. Is there any way to do this?? Please share any ideas... Thanks..

Comment: Please show some code

Comment: <bo:NavLink ui:field="examsLink" name="OW" title="View Exams" text="Exams"/>
      
<bo:NavLink ui:field="test" name="RR" title="View Test"text="Test"/>   these are the links in my uibinder file. "bo" indicates gwt-bootstrap component. how to know which link is selected??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways you can solve this:

- Put all your 50+ `NavLinks` into a panel (i.e. `FlowPanel`, `HTMLPanel`, etc)  and use `addDomHandler` (if you use a `FocusPanel` you can just use `addClickHandler()`) to add a `Clickhandler` to your `Panal`. Of couse in this case `event.getSource()` will not be your `NavLink` but your `Panel`. So you have to retrieve the real click target using something like this:

Solution 1:

```
public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
    Element targetElem = Element.as(event.getNativeEvent().getEventTarget());
    Widget targetWidget = null;

    //LOOP through all NavLinks and check 
    if (navLink.getElement().isOrHasChild(targetElem) {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

- Add a `ClickHandler` to all your 50 `NavLink`s. I guess you will create your 50+ `NavLink`s generically in a loop.

Solution 2:

```
ClickHandler clickHandler = new ClickHandler( {
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event)  {
         NavLink navLink = (NavLink)event.getSource();
    }
}

List<String> screens; // your factory returns a list of strings
for (String screen: screens) {
    NavLink navLink = new NavLink(); 
    navLink.setText(screen); 
    navLink.addClickHandler(clickHandler);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can extend Navlink with a class that register a click handler on it at construction time.

The click handler send a custom click event through an EventBus with all information that you need (name, link value, link parent). Therefore you listen the custom click event on that bus getting the information that you need.

The nasty thing is that the events come from any page/component containing the new Navlink component, but you can distinguish the provenance using the Navlink parent.

Comment: This actually is the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a multi-catch UIHandler like this

```
@UiHandler({"examsLink", "test"})
protected void onLinkClick(ClickEvent e) {
    NavLink n = (NavLink) e.getSource();
    n.getName(); // ...
}
```

then, you could:

- group links with common behavior in a single handler method.
- use an enum or some method to retrieve the NavLink based on its properties.

Comment: Currently there are more than 50 links, in future it may reach 100. So, this way i have to go on adding link names..is there any other way...

Comment: But anyway you'll have to write code for each of those 100 links isn't it ? And there is a great change each link will have a different action I guess ? In your case, 100 links names might be better than 100 UI handler. If you want you can write some js/jquery to parse the DOM and find all the links on the page. If this doesn't answer your question please be more precise about your final purpose so I can tell you the best way to reach it.

Comment: I have got one way. Currently all links are under htmlpanel. Following code illustrates this.   htmlPanel.addDomHandler(new ClickHandler() {
   
   @Override
   public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
    NavLink navLink = (NavLink) event.getSource();
    Window.alert("link clicked-->"+navLink.getName());
    
   }
  }, ClickEvent.getType());       But i am getting one exception that "event.getSource()" cannot be casted to "Navlink"..

Comment: Could you explain what your final purpose is by doing so ?

Comment: Each link displays an individual screen. When i click on that link, new screen gets displayed. I have got one navigation factory kind of class which has got unique name for each link and this unique name must be given for navlink components Eg: <bo:NavLink name="RR" title="View Test" text="Test"/> here name "RR" is that unique name. when i click on link i should get this name and then from factory class i will display corresponding screen for that link. Hope this may clear...

Comment: Ok. The DomHandler solution won't work because GWT handlers prevent event bubbling http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486137/why-gwt-event-bubbling-doesnt-work So the getSource() return the HTMLPanel, not the navLink. You have to add a handler on each navLink.

Comment: Ok.. Please show me an example with code how to add handler for each navlink. Currently there are 50+ navlinks. Thanks..

Comment: To do this just check the sample code in my answer. Sorry you'll have to type them all...